# Как сделать реляционный INSERT в  "родительскую и дочернею " базы одновременно

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Всем привет. Есть таблица tbl_test (вопросы) и есть таблица tbl_ans(ответы).

tbl_test:

1. id
2. title

tbl_ans:

1. id
2. title
3. right(yes, no)
4. test_id (foreign key)

Хочу сделать для удобства клиента форму создания теста и форму создания ответов одной формой. Вопрос как сделать так чтобы при создании теста, создавались одновременно и ответы? Можно ли в принципе сотворить такое? Или только сначала тесты потом ответы? Надеюсь вы поняли о чем я.

Проект делается на YII.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionCreate()  {
    $Test=new Test;
    $Ans=new    Ans;        
    if(isset($_POST['Test']))       {
        $Test->attributes=$_POST['Test'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$Test->id));
    }
    //И тут заполняем новый экземпляр класса Ans  как и с
    //Test   или в блоке   if
    //$Ans->attributes=
    // С данными полученными с формы мы можем делать что хотим
    ));     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону SQL деклараций `on update cascade` и `on insert cascade` - это по сути триггеры которые делают вставку/апдейт в связанные таблицы. Некоторые православные прогеры считают что каскадные вставки это зло - так что смотрите. Если все правильно сделать получается иногда удобно.